# Why is "text-align: center" striked through in Chrome "Inspect element"?

Tags: css, google-chrome, datatables

I have 2 different webpages [using DataTables to display and hide row details](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html).

Both webpages have the following CSS in their headers:

```
h1, h2, h3, p, div, form { 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

This works in the [webpage 1](http://preferans.de/DE15400) and the green plus image in the first table  column (on the left) is centered (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxM7J.png)):

[image: webpage 1]

However in the [webpage 2](http://preferans.de/misere.php) the green plus image is not centered (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFyXa.png)):

[image: webpage 2]

What is please the reason for that and why does Google Chrome strikes through the `text-align: center` when I right-click at the green plus image and select "Inspect element"?

**UPDATE:**

Yes, I can see `text-align: start` in the "Computed" tab (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PvAc.png)):

[image: screenshot]

But where does it come from? What is a "user agent stylesheet"?

And why doesn't it apply in the webpage 1?

Comment: it means there is another element of css had already declare the name attribute, you can see that there is two css with element `table`, and css choose the later, so the first will be ignore

Comment: You have a "text-align: start" on you're table.

Comment: Add table to that css: h1, h2, h3, p, div, form, table { text-align: center; }

Comment: Where does `text-align: start` for my table come from?

Comment: Take a look at the file misere.php on line 10

Comment: @Eric misere.php line 10 has `text-align: center` and not `text-align: start`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the rule "text-align:center" has been overwritten by another rule (i.e. "text-align: start").
There are three way to overwrite a rule:

1) The overwriting rule is present in the same css file of the overwritten rule, but in a lower position.

2) The overwriting rule is present in an another css file, linked after the css file containig the overwritten rule.

3) The overwriting rule is declared inside the html file throught the  tag or the style attribute.

Comment: 4) Some scripts that dinamically change the css property values. (ad es. http://api.jquery.com/css/ ).

Comment: I loaded yout page on my pc with chome browser. I don't see any "text-align: start" in the "Computed" tab., nor elsewhere. Maybe it is due to some browser plugin installed on your pc.

Comment: I have tried the webpage http://preferans.de/misere.php in Google Chrome incognito mode (i.e. with plugins disabled) and still have the issue: the green plus image in the left table column is not centered.

Comment: Inside your css definition there is

        div#header{
              .....
              text-color: #CCCCCC 
              ...... 
             }

Text-color property does not exist. Remove it and it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I removed the `text-color` and nothing changed.

Comment: Not really, I've added the `table` to `text-align: center` in my CSS

Comment: 5) In Django the css for a regular html file will be subordinate to and overruled by the rules that are set in the base.html file. Block tags can then be used to overwrite rules in base.html see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/